# What does "T" mean in "git status"? (it isn't in the man page)

Tags: git

When I type `git status` I see:

```
T /path/to/file...
M /path/to/otherfile...
```

What exactly does the `T` `git status` mean?

I tried `man git-status` (I think it *should* be there, but isn't).

Comment: See also ['typechange' in the git-status output](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/typechange-in-the-git-status-output-tp6170106p6170137.html).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It means that the type of a file changed. For example, a symbolic link that became a regular file.

As far as I know, this only applies to symlinks, submodules and regular files

**Edit**
A source was requested for this information. While this is simply information that's in my head, I was able to find a few references to it on the internet. The most prominent one was [a git changelog](https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.2.txt) mentioning "T" as a type change and "D" as a deletion.

**Edit 2** <sup>*(updating this because it's my highest rating answer so far)*</sup>
As pointed out by @PhilipOakley, `man git-diff-files` actually does show this information.

> Possible status letters are:
>
> - A: addition of a file
> - C: copy of a file into a new one
> - D: deletion of a file
> - M: modification of the contents or mode of a file
> - R: renaming of a file
> - T: change in the type of the file
> - U: file is unmerged (you must complete the merge before it can be committed)
> - X: "unknown" change type (most probably a bug, please report it)

As pointed out by @Mat, it's also in `diff.h`, line 289:

```
#define DIFF_STATUS_TYPE_CHANGED    'T'
```

And in `wt-status.c`, line 282:

```
case DIFF_STATUS_TYPE_CHANGED:
    status_printf_more(s, c, _("typechange: %s"), one);
    break;
```

Comment: Could you give some source of your information?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Git source, `diff.h` around line 289 / `wt-status.c` around line 282 @sidtj.

Comment: @Mat Don't you think that you took *source* a little bit too literally? ;-)

Comment: :) It _is_ the ultimate source though.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt, thank you for the source. It is valid to me since there is no other.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mat, I have no time now but i will check your information when i have. Thank you too.

Comment: I am curious why it isn't documented in the man page (like the OP said, it *should* be there). Maybe it just slipped.

Comment: There was a recent discussion on git@vger.kernel.org about it not being listed. IIRC the summary was that they would list the common values in `git status` and leave the special cases for deeper reading ;-)

Comment: OK so how do you get git to state what the file was changed from and to? Git diff shows the files were deleted and recreated somehow (I think through some composer require), but I can't tell what git status means specifically by file type change for each file.

Answer (score 10):

The code letters are listed in `git-diff-files` and `git-diff-index` under the `--diff-filter` option. They include these less common ones not listed under `git-status`.

> have their type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, …) changed (**T**),

From `git help diff-files` msysgit version 1.7.8-preview20111206

Answer (score 2):

> it isn't in the man page

It will be, with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021): a few kinds of changes "[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9875c515535860450bafd1a177f64f0a478900fa/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> can show were not documented. There are now.

See [commit d2a534c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2a534c515e5a0e0e38f077edf28b0eb4c1f011f), [commit 56c4d7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56c4d7f6a9ece432cd657ecfa5d3061b47ea0622), [commit 55e7f52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55e7f52b407dffc8aead377bff2ca3356dfde3e6), [commit 1566cdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1566cdd4aea973592ef1871197bc3d6b74b42d7e) (04 Oct 2021) by [Johannes Altmanninger (`krobelus`)](https://github.com/krobelus).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9875c51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9875c515535860450bafd1a177f64f0a478900fa), 13 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation/git-status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56c4d7f6a9ece432cd657ecfa5d3061b47ea0622): document porcelain status T (typechange)
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Altmanninger</sup>

> As reported in [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8311), `T` is missing from the description of porcelain status letters in `git-status` (whereas `T` *is* documented in git-`diff-files` and friends).
> Document `T` right after `M` (modified) because the two are very similar.

`git status` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/56c4d7f6a9ece432cd657ecfa5d3061b47ea0622/Documentation/git-status.txt#L210):

> - 'T' = file type changed (regular file, symbolic link or submodule)

`git status` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/56c4d7f6a9ece432cd657ecfa5d3061b47ea0622/Documentation/git-status.txt#L221-L223):

> ```
> M        [ MTD]  updated in index
> T        [ MTD]  type changed in index
> A        [ MTD]  added to index
> ```

`git status` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/56c4d7f6a9ece432cd657ecfa5d3061b47ea0622/Documentation/git-status.txt#L225-L230):

> ```
> R        [ MTD]  renamed in index
> C        [ MTD]  copied in index
> [MTARC]          index and work tree matches
> [ MTARC]    M    work tree changed since index
> [ MTARC]    T    type changed in work tree since index
> [ MTARC]    D    deleted in work tree
> ```

---

The description stems from `git diff-format`, which has been updated:

See [commit d2a534c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2a534c515e5a0e0e38f077edf28b0eb4c1f011f), [commit 56c4d7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56c4d7f6a9ece432cd657ecfa5d3061b47ea0622), [commit 55e7f52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55e7f52b407dffc8aead377bff2ca3356dfde3e6), [commit 1566cdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1566cdd4aea973592ef1871197bc3d6b74b42d7e) (04 Oct 2021) by [Johannes Altmanninger (`krobelus`)](https://github.com/krobelus).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9875c51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9875c515535860450bafd1a177f64f0a478900fa), 13 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation/diff-format`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55e7f52b407dffc8aead377bff2ca3356dfde3e6): state in which cases porcelain status is `T`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Altmanninger</sup>

> Porcelain status letter `T` is documented as "type of the file", which is technically correct but not enough information for users that are not so familiar with this term from systems programming.
>
> In particular, given that the only supported file types are "regular file", "symbolic link" and "submodule", the term "file type" is surely opaque to the many(?) users who are not aware that symbolic links can be tracked - I thought that a "`chmod +x`" could cause the `T` status (wrong, it's `M`).
>
> Explicitly document the three file types so users know if/how they want to handle this.

`diff-format` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55e7f52b407dffc8aead377bff2ca3356dfde3e6/Documentation/diff-format.txt#L62):

> - `T`: change in the type of the file (regular file, symbolic link or submodule)

Answer (score 0):

If you find binary files in your repo have changed, and you're not sure why, and you see `typechange` come up - it may mean that the mode, ie chmod, of the files has changed.

I had this pop up recently, and it wasn't immediately obvious what had changed, even after reverting to the previous commit. Only on creating a branch, and adding the reverted commits to it, did I see a message that revealed the mode had changed:

> mode change 100755 => 120000