# git pull U, A and D tags: Meaning?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-pull

git pull occasionally will give me messages as follows:

[image: screen shot of gitbash during pull attempt]

I do not understand the tags of "U", "A", and "D". Can someone please tell me what these mean?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see those letters detailed in [`man git diff-files`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-files):

```
A: addition of a file
D: deletion of a file
U: file is unmerged (you must complete the merge before it can be committed)
```

Other letters are listed at "[What does “`T`” mean in “`git status`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691226/6309)"

```
C: copy of a file into a new one
D: deletion of a file
M: modification of the contents or mode of a file
R: renaming of a file
T: change in the type of the file
X: "unknown" change type (most probably a bug, please report it)
```

---

Regarding the "`Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files`" error message, it is consistent with the "U" (unmerged files) you see in the output.
See "[Why does git say “Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26376832/6309)"

> To resolve this, you will have to resolve the merge conflicts in question, and add and commit the changes, before you can do a `git pull`.